# Disabled checkbox if the value is in database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

Hello guys can help me? about how I disabled a checkbox if the value of checkbox is already in database I have inserted value of 1A,1B in database, but suddenly all the checkbox is disabled :( here's my simple code

```
 <?php
    //Connections
$server_name='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='admin';
$db_name='matnogreservationv2';
$con= mysqli_connect($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Failed..!!'.mysqli_connect_errno();
} 
>?


//code for disabling checkbox
$resulta= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat WHERE SeatStatus = 1");
$display = mysqli_num_rows($resulta);
$con->query($display);
$disable = $display ? 'disabled="disabled"': '';

<input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1A" value="1A"  <?php echo $disable; ?>>
          <label for="1A">1A</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1B" value="1B" <?php echo $disable; ?>>
          <label for="1B">1B</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1C" value="1C"<?php echo $disable; ?>>
          <label for="1C">1C</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]"  id="1D" value="1D"<?php echo $disable; ?>>
          <label for="1D">ID</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1E" value="1E"<?php echo $disable; ?>>
          <label for="1E">1E</label>

          <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1F" value="1F"<?php echo $disable; ?>>
          <label for="1F">1F</label>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5HNb.png)

Comment: operational security my friend

Comment: `$con->query($display);` What is this?

Comment: $resulta contains single record or multiple ?

Comment: you have to use for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
...
$display = 0;
$resulta= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat WHERE SeatStatus = 1");
if ($resulta) $display = mysqli_num_rows($resulta);
//$con->query($display);  unnecessary code
$disable = ($display >= 1)? 'disabled="disabled"': '';

?>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what `$display` contains. If you want to disabled the checkbox based on `$display` value I will do like below .

```
$resulta= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat WHERE SeatStatus = 1");
//$display = mysqli_num_rows($resulta); // dont now why you want this
$seats= array(); // array look like this : array("1B","1D","1F")

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $resulta ) ){
  $seats[] = $row['seat'];
}
```

Now disable the checkbox based on the value contained in `$seats` array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1B" value="1B" <?php echo (in_array("1B", $seats)?"disabled='disabled'":"") ?>>
<label for="1B">1B</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1C" value="1C" <?php echo (in_array("1C", $seats)?"disabled='disabled'":"") ?>>
<label for="1C">1C</label>
```

Comment: Thanks sir but I got an error undefined index :seat in line 219.   which is $seats[]=$row['seat'];

Comment: @matias Then put your dynamic column name instead of 'seat'

Comment: sir dynamic column like? Im sorry im new in php. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If we imagine your table called test, something like below:

[image]

then we can have this code:

```
<?php
    //Connections
$server_name='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='admin';
$db_name='matnogreservationv2';
$con= mysqli_connect($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Failed..!!'.mysqli_connect_errno();
}



//code for disabling checkbox
$resulta= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from test");
$display = mysqli_num_rows($resulta);
$array_results = mysqli_fetch_all($resulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$values = array("1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F");
$array_values = array_column($array_results, 'value');

foreach ($values as $key => $value)
{
        $index = array_search($value, $array_values);

        if ($index === false) // if the value was not exist in the table
            $disable = '';
        elseif ($array_results[$index]['display'] == 1) // if the value was exist in table but its display status was 1
            $disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
        else
            $disable = '';
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="<?php echo $value?>" value="<?php echo $value?>"  <?php echo $disable; ?>>
    <label for="<?php echo $value?>"><?php echo $value?></label>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping me :) so I need to put values = array("1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F"); up to 10F since my checkbox is from 1A-1F to 10A-10F. Right?

Comment: @Matias Actually you dont have to do that, you can put them in another table, depends on your scenario. But the sort of them it's not important for above solution.